# Setting up Confluence DataCenter in cluster multinode

Tags: cluster-computing, confluence

Im gonna set up our Confluence Data Center in a multinode mode.
Following the next URL (https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/starting-a-confluence-cluster-on-a-single-machine/) i see how to do it in the same machine.

If i see the next documentation: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/set-up-a-confluence-data-center-cluster-982322030.html
apparently we have to create a shared directory to which all the nodes have access. I guess that have a sense if the nodes are in the same machine.
If we set the second node in a different machine to the first node, it is still necessary create a shared directory between nodes, and if yes in which machine ? (node1 or node2)
Thanks!!

Im expecting to understand the difference between setting the cluster in the same machine and different machines